# How to set up Smarty on Koding?

Tags: smarty, koding

im new to koding, and I want to use Smarty, and just want to know some details how to set up smarty om koding?
I have following code in my index.php, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
require_once './Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setCompileDir('./templates_c');
$smarty->setTemplateDir('./templates');
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What error(s) you get?

Comment: I dont got any errors. the smarty.class.php can reach, but can't display tpl file.